# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to run a fucntion on a click event with `stopPropagation` and its giving me error like:
`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`

```
<span className="selectedValue" onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); runSelect;}}>25 Miles</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually calling `runSelect`. Try this:

```
<span className="selectedValue" onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); runSelect();}}>25 Miles</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped, How to call a single function on multiple items click, for example, call a single function on every LI click in react.?

Comment: Either add a onClick to every LI or add a onClick to a common parent of all the LI's and test whether the click element is (within) the LI